# Install language pack via command line

Tags: windows-server, language-pack, windows-server-2016

I want to install additional language pack to Windows Server 2016 Evaluation Edition as a part of packer or vagrant provisioning.

I found [this answer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b9460913-e260-42e5-bc41-009e7dc1f37c/language-pack-for-windows-server-2016?forum=WinServerPreview) telling how to install additional language packs using GUI:

> Control Panel –> Language -> Add Language -> Danish –> Add Click on
>   Options (for the language you selected) -> Windows Display language ->
>   Download and install language pack

But how can I do this using command line?

Answer (score 6):

Try the command:

```
Dism /online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\test\LangPacks\lp.cab
```

See: [Add and Remove Language Packs on a Running Windows Installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dn898471(v=vs.94))

Comment: Is it possible to fetch `.cab` automatically? Looks like I have no access to Microsoft OEM for getting this `.cab`.

Comment: I was able to find the ISO on a non-Microsoft site, but no I don't know of any way to accomplish this without having the .CAB file.

Comment: You can also use: `lpksetup.exe /i * /p <path>`

Comment: ISO Language packs can be found from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/windows-11-language-packs).

Answer (score -1):

This site is supposed to make things clear....
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-language-packs-to-windows
Lot of material for a few language files....

Comment: Your answer should have all relevant information contained within it.  All outside sources, should be quoted and cited, link-only answers are not helpful.